V academic exchange Colombia visa and return flight
I am in the process of trying to obtain a V Intercambio académico (https://www.cancilleria.gov.co/tramites_servicios/visa/requisitos) visa for my daughter, a French citizen and resident who will be on an academic exchange with a faculty in Bogota (Colombia) for at least ten months beginning in july 2024.
The requested documents list does not mention air tickets or return flight ticket. I have difficulties to understand if a return flight ticket is mandatory when arriving in Colombia with such a visa ? Does any one here has some information about this or is able to check what timatic says about such a case ? (Will the flight from EU to Bogota require a return ticket to board ?).
I would prefer not to have to purchase a return ticket now as we don't know exactly when she will return and whether she will fly back to France or spend some time in America as a tourist before returning to France.
Posted in Expatriate because of the long term journey, feel free to move to travel if appropriate.
(edit July 16 2024)
I can now confirm that my daughter has been able to board the flight from EU to Bogota and enter Colombia with a V Estudiante visa without any one asking for a return ticket.

I don't really have the answer, but usually a residence visa never requires a return flight

Hard to prove a negative however I agree with @Nicolas Formichella. Inputting dummy trip details into IATA there’s no option for ‘student’ and the system response only refers to visitors requiring a return ticket.  Timatic gives the same response. Not posting as an answer as someone may have better knowledge / an official Columbian Immigration source.

According to the link you sent, effective October 2021 the V Intercambio Académico was changed to V Estudiante. https://www.cancilleria.gov.co/v/estudiante The requirements listed here state that the length of the Visa may be up to 2 years and there are no requirements shown for return ticket.
In comparison, the requirements for a V Turismo do indicate that a return ticket will be required at entry.
